# Searching from Start Menu not working

Tags: windows-10

By pressing "Windows Key" and then simply typing in an app name like "Outlook" my Windows 10 would automatically bring up Outlook.

This week my ability to "search" the Start Menu disappeared.

Even if I manually click on the magnifying glass button next to the search menu (see below), I cannot seem to enter text into this field.

Is there a solution to this?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify your question, what version of Windows 10, are you using exactly?  You can edit your question

Comment: Thanks. Edited it now to say Windows 10

Comment: I was looking for what version of Windows 10. It was obvious you were using Windows 10.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I misread. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the basic Windows 10 fixes (tag say windows 7, search bar says Windows 10).

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

This should repair the task bar functions.

If, for any reason, the initial repair steps do not work, then use the Windows 10 Repair Install.

[Windows 10 Repair Install](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

This will launch the Repair and proceed through the questions. I always start with Keep Everything.

Comment: I get stuck on step (4) C:\Windows\system32>SFC /SCANNOW  ------

Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.

Comment: @ziptron - Edit your question. You being unable to run SFC is relevant information.  Be sure trustedinstaller service is started (net start trustedinstaller)

Comment: I suggest you try a Windows 10 repair now. Answer amended accordingly.